# Which platform are GMail server side JavaScript running on?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail, ringojs

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525199/what-server-side-language-is-gmail-written-in) and [this article](http://www.infoworld.com/d/developer-world/google-executive-frustrated-java-c-complexity-375), GMail server side is written in JavaScript. I'm wondering which platform is GMail server side JavaScript running on. Node.js? RingoJS?

Comment: The linked question actually states that GMail is written in Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: @Nathan, read further ;)

Comment: But what how could we find out what platform is Gmail's Javascript is running? Is it too dificult that they have built it theirselves? just noting there is 443k lines of js code...

Comment: Well, I happened to overheard two engineers chatting in public traffic bus. One engineer told the other:"GMail team told me that their server side code is all JavaScript now." ...

Comment: I would put a bit of salt in this article: the authors says that "JavaScript is one of a whole batch of languages -- others include Ruby and Python -- that have been developed over the past 10 years in response to the growing complexity of C++ and Java". These languages are considerably older than that and were not developed as an alternative to C++ or Java but as tools for some specific work - such as client-side automation, quick scripting or didactic purposes.

Answer (score 3):

it's **GSE** platform :)

```
$ curl -I http://mail.google.com
...
Server: GSE
...
```

note that google web runs on a different platform, *gws* (google web server?)

it might be google servlet engine (OpenGSE) or something completely different..

the mail data itself (not only the web) also comes with the same header (as intercepted in a browser)

however, it's still the web interface, i did not check SMTP servers, if you were interested in that

the question "which javascript engine is it running?" remains open (if it even makes a sense)